# Does python sorted() look at the first parameter and ignore the rest?

Tags: python, sorting

The results of print statements in the last 2 lines are the same. Is there any effect when you add any more variables past the 1st one?

```
class Student:
        def __init__(self, name, grade, age):
                self.name = name
                self.grade = grade
                self.age = age
        def __repr__(self):
                return repr((self.name, self.grade, self.age))
        def weighted_grade(self):
                return 'CBA'.index(self.grade) / float(self.age)

student_objects = [
        Student('john', 'A', 15),
        Student('jane', 'B', 12),
        Student('dave', 'B', 10),
]

print sorted(student_objects, key=lambda student: student.age)
print sorted(student_objects, key=lambda student: (student.age, student.grade))
```

I always get

```
[('dave', 'B', 10), ('jane', 'B', 12), ('john', 'A', 15)]
[('dave', 'B', 10), ('jane', 'B', 12), ('john', 'A', 15)]
```

I would have thought John have the 'A' grade would have pushed him somewhere else. Or should I have added more students objects and/or fields?

Comment: Write `help(sorted)` in the Interactive Python Interpreter and it'll show you the documentation for it.

Comment: Why would it give your expected output? There is no "tie-break" in your example for which to have `grade` make any difference.

Comment: What @roganjosh is saying is to try it again, but make dave and john have the same age.

Comment: In the second sort, your key is (age, grade), meaning it sorts first by age, then by grade as a tie-breaker.  Since all of the ages are different, the second part of the sort key isn't needed.  It really wouldn't make any sense for it to behave differently.

Comment: Result is correct. John is the oldest guy so he will come last. Maybe you should sort by grade first then age: `print sorted(student_objects, key=lambda student: (student.grade, student.age))`? So people with `A` will come first and the rest is sorted by their age.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to sort by the tuple given in the key function, which will sort by first element, and for tuples with equal first elements, the second, and so on. Since they all have unique ages, it will simply be sorted by their age. If you did `(student.grade, student.age)`, `'john'` would be first, followed by `'dave'` and `'jane'` as they appear now.

Comment: The OP is not trying to sort a tuple. They're sorting a list of custom objects and sorting by object attributes.

Comment: The key they are using is a tuple. Therefore, they are sorting tuples created from the objects' attributes, which correspond to the object.

Comment: @roganjosh I think the point Sebastian is trying to make is that providing the `key` function basically says *sort as if these objects looked liked these tuples instead*.

Comment: Ok, i definitely didnt read it like that. Please add sort _by_ and I'll remove my downvote. "Sort a tuple" is not what they're doing.

Comment: "sort by the tuple given in the key function" does that make more sense?

Comment: Yes, much. Thanks:)